React Query - Not Caching API Response
Problem:
Trying to get caching working with react-query. The code seems to be correct as I'm using both staleTime and cacheTime, but it keeps re-fetching data every after page reload. It's not supposed to. It's supposed to serve the cached data and stop fetching. There's no console errors, either.
What I've Tried:
Using staleTime and cacheTime in order to cache, but it's not caching.
Code:
Link to full code.
App.tsx:
import { useQuery } from "react-query";
import { fetchProducts } from "../src/services/api/Api";

function App() {
  // Fetch the data
  const { data, isLoading, error } = useQuery("products", fetchProducts, {
    // Set stale/cache time
    staleTime: 1000 * 60 * 5, 
    cacheTime: 1000 * 60 * 10,
    refetchOnWindowFocus: true,
  });

  return (
    <>
      <ChakraProvider>
        <Container maxW="1200px">
          <Header data={data} isLoading={isLoading} error={error} />
          <MainTable data={data} isLoading={isLoading} error={error} />
        </Container>
      </ChakraProvider>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

API.tsx (API Fetch Function):
import axios from "axios";
export const fetchProducts = async () => {
  try {
    const urlEn = "url-here";
    const urlFr = "url-here-fr-CA";

    // if URL contains /fr, load in FR API
    // else, load in EN API
    const urlParts = window.location.pathname.split("/");
    const mainUrl = urlParts.includes("fr") ? urlFr : urlEn;

    const response = await axios.get(mainUrl);
    const products = response.data.groups;
    console.log("Fetched data in API component:", products);
    return products;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
    throw error;
  }
};



but it keeps re-fetching data every after page reload

The React Query cache lives in memory, so if you hard reload the page, the cache is always empty. This is the expected behaviour. If you want persisted caching, you have to take a look at the persister plugins:
https://tanstack.com/query/v5/docs/framework/react/plugins/persistQueryClient
